# Not able to get image as json response using angularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am getting image in json response form restful api and I have to use that image in html using angularjs.

I dont know how can I use that image using angularJs

If I am trying like that **"http:/api/image/id"** where id is **"userID"**. But when I write the code in angularjs I didnt get any response.I tried to debug code by using breakpoints and but it didn't go inside the function

**JS Code**

```
QAApp.controller('imgCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.image = function (id) {
       var request = $http({
                          method: 'GET', 
                          url: server + 'api/image/' + id,
                        });
            request.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              console.log(data);

            });
          }
      });
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="artst-pic pull-left" ng-controller="imgCtrl">
      <img ng-show = "{{image(q.userID)}}" alt="" class="img-responsive" />K
</div>
```

Please tell me how can I use this.

Comment: Would help if you could post what your JSON looks like.

Comment: I am not able to post json response, by using this url http://localhost:8000/api/image/id, then it will display the image directly not url, so i have to display that image...I didnt get any solution how I can use it.......where /api/image/id this is the api path ...

Comment: Object {data: "����JFIFHH���ExifMM*…������f�*�c#���B���z�����h���)Ob��5��o�QY��", status: 200, headers: function, config: Object}..... I am getting json response like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, the API directly sends you the image, not any JSON..

Then just display it like you would display any image (you don't need ajax):

JS

```
$scope.image = function (id) {
    return server + 'api/image/' + id;
};
```

HTML

```
<img ng-src="{{image(q.userID)}}"/>
```

Comment: Depends if you have access to server side code or not. Anyhow, I encourage you to post a new question with more information on that matter.

Comment: I didn't have access to server side, if image is not present the that API path return json response with "No image found", so if this message is come at that time I have to use dummy image....

Answer (score 1):

Javascript

```
QAApp.controller('imgCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

      $scope.image = function (id) {
             $http({
                              method: 'GET', 
                              url: server + 'api/image/' + id,
                            }).then(function(data){
                             $scope.imageUrl= data; // if you sure what data is you URL 
                       })
              }
          });
```

HTML

```
<div class="artst-pic pull-left" ng-controller="imgCtrl">
      <img ng-src="{{imageUrl}}" ng-init="image(q.userID)" alt="" class="img-responsive" />K
</div>
```

Comment: please tell me how can I do this, I posted my json response also, please see, how can I solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

The Apache Roller source code has an example of using angular.js to bring in an image source: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/roller/trunk/app/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsps/editor/ThemeEdit.jsp?annotate=1621546 (line 126, with the JavaScript at the bottom of the file).